# Bicycle band brake

Tags: brakes

How do you get one to work ? Mine has been almost useless from the start producing almost imperceptible retardation. With regard to the screw at the top the seller thought it was to oil it with ? Help.

Comment: If the seller put oil anywhere near a drum brake, it might have migrated to the drum itself rendering it useless.

Comment: If there's no oil involved and its been bad since new, then it could be a technique thing where you're not moving body weight to the back while braking, or it could be a glazed braking surface.    Can you please use edit to expand your question with a bit more info ?

Answer (score 1):

No - you don't ever oil the friction surfaces of a brake.  Ever.

If you have oiled it then try this repair:

1. Take your back wheel out of the bike.  This will require disconnecting the brake cable.
2. Remove the cover of your band brake - inside should be the pull-lever and 340 degrees of flexible band.  The whole brake is dead if the oil has contaminated this flexible brake band.
3. Inspect brake drum on the wheel axle.  I bet its oily.  Clean the brake drum using a solvent - I'd use petrol but a degreaser might smell better.
4. You need to remove the oil from the brake band.  I've done this on contaminated car brake shoes using heat from a blowtorch and rags to soak up brake fluid from the surface.  You'll have to repeat this heat/pat cycle a bunch of times.
5. Reassemble and refit.  You can test the band brake on the drum by hand before reinstalling it in the wheel.

The ~two screws are used to adjust the resting position of the band over the drum - they allow for wear of the braking surface over time.

If the brake band doesn't improve it may be too far gone, and a replaceement brake band is the fix.

### NEVER OIL BRAKE FRICTION PARTS

The only part that might need oiling is the moving pivot of the 90 degree lever that connects the band to the brake inner wire.  Even then its barely a drop of light oil.